# Appropriate c# collection for fast search by multy keys

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures, collections

Hello i'm working on refactoring some legacy code. There some code that represents something like "converter" from custom type to c# type.

```
          ...
           if (dataType == CustomType.Bit)
            {
                return typeof(bool);
            }
            else if (dataType == CustomType.Bittype ||
                dataType == CustomType.Char ||
                dataType == CustomType.Fromtotype ||
                dataType == CustomType.Mdcintervaltype ||
                dataType == CustomType.Nclob ||
                dataType == CustomType.Nchar ||
                dataType == CustomType.Ntext ||
                dataType == CustomType.Nvarchar ||
                dataType == CustomType.Nvarchar2 ||
                dataType == CustomType.Varchar ||
                dataType == CustomType.Varchar2)
            {
                return typeof(string);
            }
            else if (dataType == CustomType.Date ||
                dataType == CustomType.Datetime ||
                dataType == CustomType.Timestamp3 ||
                dataType == CustomType.Timestamp6)
            {
                return typeof(DateTime);
            }
            else if (dataType == CustomType.Decimal ||
                dataType == CustomType.Money ||
                dataType == CustomType.Number ||
                dataType == CustomType.Numeric)
            {
                return typeof(decimal);
            }
```

...

**Q:** I'm looking for some C# structure (collection or not) that would be able to help me with fast search with *one to many relonships*. (i.e i would like something that look like **{ Collection possible keys} ==>  { value }**

**P.s** I think that simple Dictionary where each Custromtype is key and return the same type isn't "beatiful"

```
new Dictionary<string, Type>()(){
    { CustomType.Bittype, typeof(string)},
    { CustomType.Fromtotype, typeof(string)}
     ...
    { CustomType.Datetime,  typeof(DateTime)},
    { CustomType.Date, typeof(DateTime)}
    ....
}
```

Comment: Dictionary or switch is your friend. Sometimes code isn't beautiful, take a loot at Microsoft source code. however the beauty is in elegant design, i'e doing things in a robust, readable, and maintainable way

Comment: Do you have control over those `CustomType`s? If so, they could have a read-only Field of `Type` that returns the desired conversion type.

Comment: Another option is to add a custom attribute to every member of `CustomType` containing matching `Type` and then either use reflect straight away to get the `Type`, or prepare a cache using dictionary or similar structure.
PS. I'd have added a unit test for presence of said attribute so should the number of `CustomType` members change there wouldn't be a chance to miss the attribute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make `Dictionary` a bit more *beautiful* if you put `string` as a default type; another suggestion is to implement it as an *extension method*

```
 public static class CustomTypeExtensions {
   private static Dictionary<CustomType, Type> s_Map = new Dictionary<CustomType, Type>() {
     {CustomType.Datetime,  typeof(DateTime)},
     {CustomType.Date, typeof(DateTime}, 
     ...
   }; 

   public static Type ToType(this CustomType value) {
     if (s_Map.TryGetValue(value, out var result))
       return result;
     else
       return typeof(string); // when not found, return string 
   }
 }
```

....

```
var custom = CustomType.Bittype;

...

Type t = custom.ToType();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry's approach is fine, also you can use something like this:

```
class Example
{
    private readonly HashSet<CustomType> _stringCompatibleTypes = new HashSet<CustomType>
    {
        CustomType.Char, CustomType.Fromtotype, CustomType.Nclob, ...
    };

    private readonly HashSet<CustomType> _dateCompatibleTypes = new HashSet<CustomType>
    {
        CustomType.Datetime, CustomType.Timestamp3, CustomType.Timestamp6, ...
    };

    // Another type sets

    public Type Foo(CustomType dataType)
    {
        if (_stringCompatibleTypes.Contains(dataType))
        {
            return typeof(string);
        }

        if (_dateCompatibleTypes.Contains(dataType))
        {
            return typeof(DateTime);
        }

        ...
    }
}
```